# How to write a Java program that generates three random integers between 0 and 50, calculates the average?

Tags: java, random, average

How to write a Java program that generates three random integers between 0 and 50, calculates the average?

My code is like this:

> 

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomAverage {


public static void main(String[] args) 
{


int num1,num2,num3;
int sum,average;
Random random = new Random();
num1 = random.nextInt(51);
num2 = random.nextInt(51);
num3 = random.nextInt(51);
sum = num1+ num2+ num3;
average = sum/3;
System.out.print("The sum of them is :" + sum);
System.out.print("The average of them is :" + average);



}

}
```

but the output said:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class stringchecker.StringChecker
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

what's wrong with that?

Comment: Was any other information provided along with that error message? Also, what is StringChecker?

Comment: Note that `average = sum / 3`; will return a truncated value due to the operation being performed in integer arithmetic. You ought to write `double average = sum / 3.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that you are running this in an IDE, and that you have not setup the "main" class correctly - more specifically, the main method is not being found in the class StringChecker, in the package stringchecker. Check the name of the class this code is in, and the package matches the name of the class and package that the IDE thinks the main method is in. This would result wherever you run it from - but it occurs quite a lot when people setup a project in an IDE that generates a "main" class for them, if they then change the structure.

Comment: yeah, i check my name and find that i cluttering them... you're so patiently and carefully. thx!

Answer (score 0):

Might Your File name for java is StringChecker and you mention class name as RandomAverage, make them same.
class RandomAverage file should be store as RandomAverage.java

Comment: yeah, my File name and class name is different ... how careless i am... Thx!